# Building Admissions - Cross Record Comparison - data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I am new to R and data.table, and my brain is wired to think in SAS, so I am looking for approaches to the following problem.

I have health bills that span a period of time "from" to "thru". I want to create admissions, where I flag all bills that are continuous (i.e. there is no more than a day between them). In the sample data below, the patient, from, and thru columns are what we are starting with, and the admit column is what I want to add.

```
Name    From    Thru    Admit
John    1/1/18  1/7/18  1
John    1/8/18  1/15/18 1
John    1/18/18 1/20/18 2
Jane    1/1/18  1/3/18  3
Jane    1/5/18  1/8/18  4
Jane    1/10/18 1/17/18 5
Jane    1/12/18 1/17/18 5
Jane    1/18/18 1/24/18 5
Frank   2/1/18  2/1/18  6
Frank   2/1/18  2/10/18 6
Frank   2/3/18  2/3/18  6
Frank   2/4/18  2/4/18  6
Frank   2/5/18  2/5/18  6
```

I'd prefer a data.table orientated solution. I need some sort of hint - in SAS I know exactly how to do this, but I'm trying to learn something new.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to use a date format (see `?Date` or `?IDate`), then could maybe do something like `DT[, g := .GRP, by=.(Name, cumsum(From - shift(Thru) > 1))]`

Comment: @josemz's code still gives the Admit column above, right? Maybe if you eliminate the second to last row..?

Answer (score 1):

Following Frank's comment, if your `data.table` is called `DT`:

```
date_cols <- c("From", "Thru")
DT[, (date_cols) := lapply(.SD, as.Date, format = "%m/%d/%y"), .SDcols = date_cols]
DT[, Admit := 1 + cumsum(From - shift(Thru, fill = Thru[1]) > 1 | 
                         Name != shift(Name, fill = Name[1]))]
DT

#    Name       From       Thru Admit
# 1: John 2018-01-01 2018-01-07     1
# 2: John 2018-01-08 2018-01-05     1
# 3: John 2018-01-18 2018-01-20     2
# 4: Jane 2018-01-01 2018-01-03     3
# 5: Jane 2018-01-05 2018-01-08     4
# 6: Jane 2018-01-10 2018-01-17     5
# 7: Jane 2018-01-12 2018-01-17     5
# 8: Jane 2018-01-18 2018-01-24     5
```

Although this assumes all the observations for each patient are consecutive, you might want to make sure that is true in your data.

Comment: Very clever, and close. It gave me stuff to work on. Still stuck with the cross record comparison for Frank. Somehow we need to remember the 2/10 thru date across a variable number of subsequent records.

Comment: This extension works for the new example, I think: `DT[, g := 1L + cumsum(
    From - shift(cummax(as.integer(Thru)), fill = Thru[1]) > 1
), by=Name][, g := .GRP, by=.(Name,g)][]` (Feel free to edit it in)

Comment: Yes - this solves the problem. Not sure how to give you "credit" for the solution.